# What music player shows "similar bands you might like" feature

Tags: 11.10, music-player

In 11.04 I used banshee or rhythmbox because it had a feature that told me, when I was listening to a song what other bands from other similar groups I would enjoy. Most of the time it was correct or at least it helped me find a group I have not heard for a long time.

In 11.10 neither of them have this feature or at least I do not know which one had it and how to activated it again.

What music player has this particular feature in 11.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Banshee still has that. You have to make sure that you have enabled the Last.FM-scrobbling plugin in the settings and then check the context pane under view to be shown.
I don't know about Rhythmbox but other than that, [Tomahawk player](http://www.tomahawk-player.org/) has a similar feature.

Comment: Also rhythmbox has the possibility to enable last-fm plugin

Answer (score 1):

I found that feature in Songbird (in Ubuntu for the moment works perfectly a sort of portable version- just unpack - I got it [here](http://wiki.songbirdnest.com/Developer/Articles/Builds/Contributed_Builds#Linux)) - a player with a lot of  custom features downloadable from within the player itself. Songbird has an internet browser: search amongst the many add-ons. I think what you need is one called [Music Recommendations](http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/1297): it's description says:"Suggests similar artists based on the currently playing song".